# Difficulty clicking <a> tag in python selenium that directs to a pop up box

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am practising my web scraping skills using the World Surf League website. I have not scraped any data, I am just at the stage of navigating the site using Selenium. However, I have encountered an issue where I am unable to 'click' on an 'a' tag that should open a pop up box within the webpage. I have tried various solutions but am ultimately unable to resolve this issue. Here is my current implementation:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = 'https://www.worldsurfleague.com/events?all=1&year=2023'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url)
link_element = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "event-schedule-details__event-name")
link_href = link_element[0].get_attribute('href')
driver.get(link_href.replace('/main', '/results'))

womens_heats = "//a[@title=\"Women's Heats\"]"
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, womens_heats)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

details_selector = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Details')[0]

print(details_selector)
next_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Details')))
actions.move_to_element(next_element).click().perform()

print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.wave-score').get_attribute('textContent'))

driver.quit()
```

Above is the code that I have used. The issue arises with the final `print` statement, which should print out a list of scores that are within the `wave-score` class, but instead it returns `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`. If you follow the code defined here you will eventually get to this page:

[WSL Event Results Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKbYq.png)

Where clicking on any of the 'Details' links will open something like this:

[WSL Event Results Details Pop Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbgpC.png)

The above is ultimately where I would like the code to get to, but I am having trouble getting there. The code provided above only returns an error at the print statement, so the actual 'clicking' of the 'Details' link doesn't throw any errors, it just doesn't work properly. Any help is hugely appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues there:

1. You don't wait for `wave_score` element visibility properly (and it opens async)
2. Ads banner can appear and intercept your click in 50% of cases.

So as a solution, you need to remove ads if they are exist.

```py
womens_heats = "//a[@title=\"Women's Heats\"]"
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, womens_heats)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
driver.execute_script("""
while(document.querySelectorAll('[class*=banner]').length > 0) {
    document.querySelector('[class*=banner]').remove();
}
""")

details_selector = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Details')[0]

print(details_selector)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
next_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Details')))
actions.move_to_element(next_element).scroll_by_amount(0, 500).perform()
next_element.click()

wave_score = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.wave-score')))
print(wave_score.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

I have rewritten your code, so now it removes ads if they exist after move to the element, and adds a wait for the visibility of the wave score element.

Comment: This has solved the issue I was having - thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @trizzo if this solved your issue, can you check this answer as correct, plz? :)